# Is this space $T_1$ and satisfies property $P$?.

Tags: general-topology

**Question**: let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $τ=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. The topological space $(X,τ)$ is said to have property $P$ if for any two proper disjoint closed subsets $Y$ and $Z$ of $X$, there exists disjoint open sets $U$, $V$ such that $Y ⊆U, Z⊆V$. Then the topological space $(X,τ)$

(A) is $T_1$ and satisfies $P$

(B) is $T_1$ but does not satisfies $P$

(C) is not $T_1$ and satisfies $P$

(D) is not $T_1$ and not satisfies $P$

I am beginner of topology, and I don't have key of above problem , so please help me....

**My attempt**: what I know is , members of $τ$ are called open sets and I know $(X,τ)$  will be $τ_1$ if Singleton's are closed set, but there is no set in $τ$ such that whose complement is $\{2\}$ and hence $\{2\}$ is not closed set in $(X,τ)$ and hence space is not $τ_1$.

Now to see whether $(X,τ)$ satisfies $P$. Clearly I can see, $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$ are closed sets(because they are complement of open sets) and they are disjoint too and clearly there exists open sets $U, V$ such that $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$ are contained in $U$ and $V$ respectively(here $U$, $V$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$ resp.) Hence $(X,τ)$ satisfies $P$.

Please check whether "my attempt" is correct or not! and **is above solution by me is complete and correct?** as i beginner and don't have key, I don't know I am correct or not.  please help me.

Comment: @PanchalShamsundar the proof is not correct, read the other answers.

Comment: yeah, all the cases were not exhausted, thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remember to add $\emptyset$ as open subset.

Your proof of $X$ not being $T_1$ is correct.

But, to prove that $X$ satisfies $P$, you have to show that *every pair* of disjoint closed subsets have disjoint open neighborhoods containing them. What you did is finding *one* pair with that property. So that part of the proof is not correct.

Comment: But Sir, are there any other pair of  proper disjoint closed sets?

Comment: $\{1\}$ and $\{3\}$

Comment: @chof sir, $\{3\}$ does not belongs to $τ$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I mean disjoint closed sets. And $3\in\{2,3\}$.

Comment: $\{1\}$ and $\{3\}$ are closed, doesn't matter wether they are in $\tau$ or not

Comment: @starshaped Sir, thank for your answer..and for last reply in comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your space is not $T_1$ since $$\{2\}^c = \{1,3\} \notin \tau$$

so $\{2\}$ is not a closed set.

All closed sets in your space are

$$\{\{2,3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{3\}, \{1\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \emptyset\}$$

The only nontrivial disjoint pairs are $(\{2,3\}, \{1\})$ and $(\{3\}, \{1\})$ both of which can be separated by $\{2, 3\}, \{1\} \in \tau$.

Therefore, your space indeed satisfies $P$ so the correct option is $(C)$.

Comment: Sir, though I like your this answer, but i saw beauty in the one that you had deleted ....Sir is your previous answer is correct?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I made a mistake before thinking that the space was $T_1$. The property $P$ alone does not imply the space must be Hausdorff (as evident here).

Comment: Sir thanks for reply, one more thing, as $τ$ does not contains $\{3\}$ so "IS" we need to verify the property $P$ for second pair, that you had mention?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi We still need to verify it because $\{3\}$ is a closed set. It is irrelevant whether $\{3\}$ is also open or not.

Comment: The proposer forgot to include the empty set among the members of  $\tau.$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but not complete.

You just found one example of two closed disjoint sets and their corresponding disjoint open sets.
Apparently there are other disjoint closed sets in your topology.

Try to find all of them.

Comment: Sir Thank you :-). If there are more closed sets, then how can one prove it without verifying for each set?

Comment: how about $\{1\} = \{2,3\}^c$ and $\{3\} = \{1,2\}^c$ ?

Comment: they are nontrivial, closed and disjoint

Comment: @starshaped What about them?

Comment: I already said, they are nontrivial, closed and disjoint

Comment: You can cover them by disjoint open sets {1} and {2,3}

Comment: You said, "While you just found one example of two closed disjoint sets and their corresponding disjoint open sets, apparently these are the only disjoint closed sets in your topology.", wich is a lie because there exists another pair.

Comment: And you told the user Akash the proof is complete, and it is not.

Comment: You are correct. I should have mentioned to Akash to check all the cases  despite my confirmation.